# Pivottable with Plotly - Can't set Locale

Tags: javascript, angular, plotly, pivottable.js

I am using Pivottable.js with Plotly and I need to set the locale for my country.

As said on [Pivot Table Documentation](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/wiki/Optional-Extra-Renderers#plotly-rendereroptions), I need to use the rendererOptions object with plotlyConfig object to override the config object from Plotly.

As described on [Plotly set Locale Documentation](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/dist/README.md#to-include-localization), I have import the Language Pack and set the "locale" property to my desired locale.

So, I have the following pivotUI call:

```
let obj = targetElement.pivotUI(
      this.data, 
      {
        renderers: renderers,
        rendererOptions: {
          plotlyConfig: {
            locale: "pt"
          }
        }
      },
      false,
      "pt"
    )
```

And in my HTML header I have the following:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My app title</title>
  <base href="/">
  <!-- Other scripts -->

  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-basic-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-locale-pt-br-latest.js"></script>  
</head>
```

But it doesn't work. The select menu still displaying in default English locale.

I'm using this pivottable.js plugin in Angular 8.

Is there anything else that I should do?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-locale-pt-br-latest.js`, wich has the languagename `name:"pt-BR"`. So you should use `locale: "pt-BR"`.